# How to count items based on 2 arguments?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

My table :

| id | rack | rack_loc | ent_date | product | serial | state | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RACK 7 | A | 05/05/2022 | ENT5000X | 8675762 | READY | READY |

I want to return the `COUNT` of products with `status` READY. I have a set with the product called `prod` (which contains same text as the `product` column). Below code results in an error:

```py
cursor.execute('''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_data WHERE product = prod AND status = 'READY';''')
```

The error :

> no such column: prod

What I expect was a returned value of 1, or more if table was full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use placeholders (`?`) and query parameters for the dynamic data.

```
prod = "ENT5000X"  # or whatever
cursor.execute(
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_data WHERE product = ? AND status = ?",
    [prod, "READY"],
)
count = cursor.fetchone()[0]  # `count` is 0 or more
```

Comment: @PyMan85 You're welcome. I suggest you read the introduction/tutorial for the `sqlite3` module; it covers this sort of thing. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html